# How to change the confirmable to be optional in devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise-confirmable

I have devise for authentication and I have `confirmable` in devise for `User` model.

- I want this to be optional based on the data I send.
- That is there is a `type field` in `User` model.
- If I send `value 1` for type then the confirmable should be present.
- if `value is 2` then there should not be confirmable and the account should be activated automatically.

How can I do this? Please help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use skip_confirmation! method here. So it will not fire confirmation mail for user and will be confirmed.

```
before_save :require_confirmation, :on => :create

def require_confirmation
   self.skip_confirmation! if field == "value_2"
end
```

Comment: If i send the value 2 then it skips confirmation and let the users sign in but if value is 1 then it displays error as            undefined method `confirmation_url' for #<#<Class:0x000001038d7c60>:0x000001038ce4f8> and the user is not created. what should i do if it should send email if value = 1?

Comment: I think.. this seems devise scoped_views related errors. Just do one thing just take backup of your project and try this step-1: just set "config.scoped_views = true" inside "config/initializers/devise.rb". step-2: Then generate scoped views using "rails generate devise:views users".

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now, but could you please tell me why you told to do these changes.

Comment: I don't know too much about devise gem. But I think there are some devise routings problem with devise default scoped views. I almost had same issue. I tried these steps and it solved my issue. You can find more on https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views

Answer (score 7):

You can just set `config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = nil` in your `**config/initializers/devise.rb**` file.

Thanks to [Ajedi32](https://github.com/Ajedi32) for the issue – https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2275

Answer (score 2):

You can make something like this in your user model.

```
before_save :confirm_user, on: :create

def confirm_user
  self.confirm! if field.eql?("value_1")
end
```

The trick is you check your value, and if you want to create user without confirmation, than you just confirm it by hand with the devise `confirm!` method.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain me in detail. I have            "devise : confirmable" in my user model. How can this method restrict confirmable

Comment: `confirm!` method confirm a user by setting it's `confirmed_at` field to actual time. If the user is already confirmed, add an error to email field.

Comment: I have used like this  before_save :skip_confirmation!, :on => :create
    
def skip_confirmation!
    self.confirmed_at = Time.now if type == "value 2"
end                                                                     it does not send mail to user if type == "value 2" but if value is 1 it displays error as undefined method `confirmation_url' for #<#<Class:0x000001038d7c60>:0x000001038ce4f8>. what can i do?